# What is position initial in CSS

Tags: css

I was searching for the difference between `position:static;` and `position:initial;` when I found the [developer mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) page where `position:static;`'s description is given but `position: initial/inherit/unset;` are global values . What are those global values meant for?

Comment: To set it to what the browser defines maybe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`initial` is not only used for `position`, it is a generic value which you can set it for any property in CSS.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial):

> The `initial` CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an
>   element. It is allowed on every CSS property and causes the element
>   for which it is specified to use the initial value of the property.

When using `initial` value, it will pick the value as defined in the spec as properties default.

Worth noting that [this is not supported in IE at all](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value) as of now, not even in IE 11, so don't use it unless you dumping support for IE users.

**How this works?**

Think of it that you have an element `p` with nested `span` with color set to `orange`, and later you use `initial` for `span` it will fall to a default value as mentioned in w3c spec.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/eLL1zyyy/2/)

```
span {
  color: red; 
  /* won't make any difference */
}

p {
  color: orange;
}

p span {
  color: initial; 
  /* sets to initial value defined in spec/user-agent */
}
```

---

Do not confuse it with `inherit`

`inherit` is something different all-together compared to `initial`. Where `initial` will pick the value from `:root`, `inherit` will take the value from it's parent. `:root` here am talking about initial values defined in the spec and is adapted by browsers.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/eLL1zyyy/1/)

```
p {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

p span {
  margin-left: inherit;
}
```

`inherit` is useful when the parent property value is not inherited by default, for example `margin`. Here, it will pick the value from it's parent declaration and not the `:root`

Comment: Just in case, note that the `initial` keyword is not supported in any version of IE: http://caniuse.com/#search=initial

Comment: @mr-alien I need a new pair of glasses ;-)

Comment: i thought initial is only for position but now i understand for everything . Thank you @Mr.Alien

Answer (score 4):

`position: initial` means that it will catch the default(initial) value so it will catch `position: static`.

You have to use `position: initial` when you have changed the default value of the `position` of an element and you want to back to the default `CSS` position property for this element.

Answer (score 3):

The value `initial` can be used on most properties - it's not unique to `position`... It simply means to default back to the browser's initial value for that element. For example:

```
h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The above overrides the browser default setting for a `h2` element, which is `display: block`.

Further down the line, if you want to override one particular `h2` to back to its default block value, you can do this:

```
.parent h2 {
    display: initial;
}
```

Which would put the display back to `block` for that `h2` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Initial puts the elements position back to the default. So if we want all `<p>` elements to have margin except one which we want to be default then we can set that.

```
div p {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.special {
   margin-left: initial;
}
```

See in more detail in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/s9zcsgfs/1/

You can also use it on things like color